# Why change color or bold in part of one cell is not working anymore?

Tags: excel, vba

In *Excel*, it was posible change the font color in part of a cell.

I've tried the below code. It's not working in updated *Excel 365* for value (not formula),

```
Set ce=cells(5,3)
ce.Characters(1, 5).Font.Color = vbBlue
```

It should change the color in 5 first characters in the cell, but it changes the color of all cell content. Even interactively it's not working. One select a piece inside a cell, press a color. When exits the cell, it colours all the cell content (in the same way of VBA code)

Why?

**Update:** It's my fault. One just can colour part of a text not a number. With text, both VBA or not works OK

Comment: Is the content of the cell the result of a formula?

Comment: It's constant, not formula

Comment: Sorry, I will correct it in the question

Comment: You may have to reset.  If you put the following line between the two lines `ce.Font.Color = vbBlack` you may see what you want.

Comment: It works as expected in Excel Professional Plus 2016.

Comment: Done, remember that I've tested interactivally

Comment: I don't know what testing interactivally means, but I am using Office 365 and 365 Pro Plus with no issues.

Comment: I too have no issues with it, Office 365 ProPlus latest edition.

Comment: My version is Office 365 Home version 1912 Build 12325.20288

Test interactivally is 
1) Go to cell, select a part of the cell, click in ´red´, click ´Enter´. The color don't change. I clear format information before this operation.

Comment: Again manually selecting a part of the text in the cell and setting the color, affects only the characters selected, at least for me.

Comment: In another sheet of same workbook  it's working, including the VBA. It's a mistery. The sheet is not protected.

Comment: I've found the mistery. One just can colour partially text not a number.

Comment: @PauloBuchsbaum: you can partially color numbers as well. But for that, change the format of the cell to Text.

Comment: I think that's a useful question, with a useful solution (disagreeing with the close vote here). Consider posting an answer, for posterity!

Comment: @SiddharthRout but then, it's no longer a number :)

Comment: Yes it is no longer a number (yet it is) @MathieuGuindon :D `ISNUMBER()` may return False but In another cell try doing BODMAS with it.

Comment: I wonder why the close vote though....... PauloBuchsbaum: It is a very less known fact that one just can colour part of a text and not a number. Like @MathieuGuindon suggested post an answer.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, if you  format as text "NumberFormat = @" doesn't work yet. Vide my below answer.

Answer (score 2):

After the discussion in comments, Excel accept partial color cell to text content, but not for number content.

So put `ABCDEFG` in a active cell. The below code colour the 5 first characters in red. Interactivally it also works.

```
ActiveCell.Characters(1, 5).Font.Color = vbRed
```

Now put `1234567` in a active cell. The below code paint all in red. Interactivally the color remains the same before.

```
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "@"   // Even if you format as text doesn't work
ActiveCell.Characters(1, 5).Font.Color = vbRed
```

The same code works if you just put a `B` before `1234567` ...

Comment: Try prefixing the number with an apostrophe/single-quote (`'`)

Comment: It works! In short, it doesn't matter if it's formatted as a number. It must be a text physically. '123 is a text. 123 formatted as text only looks like text.

Comment: Note that "text formatting" is one of the most annoying things in Excel; if these numbers/values have any kind of meaning that other cells need to use (for lookups, or for any kind of math), consider making a copy in another column, and formatting that column instead (the non-formatted values could be hidden) - that way you won't need to be fixing lookups and/or to convert text to numbers to do math against them (efficiency!), and you can still have the prettified/formatted "as text" value visible.

Comment: No it is not necessary for the cell to have `'`. It will work without that as well. See [THIS](https://prnt.sc/qoulk2)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, the curious is that 2 colour painting with VBA works if the cell is marked with green in the top left and doesn't work if not. If I start with a number and use the second code nothing happens, but if the cells is already marked with green, works ok.